# Display RSS with PHP Correctly

Tags: php, rss

I have a sample RSS from Amazon. While the RSS displays correctly with images aligned to the left, but when I try displaying the same RSS, the images do not align to the left, but to the top and this is not what I want. I need it to display exactly the same way as the one on top

I have included the [images here](http://valashiya.blogspot.com/2009/10/images.html), my display is the second on the bottom - I'd like it displayed like the one on top. Here's the [PHP code](http://pastebin.com/m2424f817) I've been using and the [RSS file](http://pastebin.com/md0a9f81).

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but is it just a CSS issue?

Comment: Please include code in the question itself. In this case, without the code, the question lacks enough detail to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define css stylesheet to format the display elements, without a stylesheet you are falling back on user / user-agent stylesheets.

for simplicity, I would reformat the html code to something meaningful:

```
<a class="link">#</a>
<div class="itemWrap">
  <img src="snooze.jpg" alt="" />
  <p class="description">lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
</div>
```

this way you can nicely float the image to the left (the div.itemWrap serves as a boundary for the floated image)

```
.itemWrap img{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.itemWrap{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

hope it helps